# Dropdown value change condition inside if satement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am new to jQuery. I was searching for a jQueryfunction which return true/false on dropdown value change. But I am unable to find one.
I want like this...
Code for Dropdown

```
<select id="kkkk" >
        </select>
```

Populating it using jQuery function.

```
 function selectOne() {
     var select = $('#kkkk')[0];
     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
         $('select option[value="0"]').attr("selected", true);
     }
 }
```

I want an if statement like this below:

```
if('#kkkk' value change)
{
//sample code
}
```

I want to run sample code only if dropdown value change.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why do you keep selecting the one option over and over again in the for loop?

Comment: Did you look at the examples on the jQuery site for [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)?

Comment: Did you check jQuery event change() ? http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @epascarello that function is selecting value 0 only on page load.

Comment: @AzAh it is selecting it on EVERY single iteration of the for loop! I formatted your code better, see the indentation, it is in the for loop. So you are querying the DOM every iteration for that element and setting it to selected, every time.

Comment: Most of the answer are same but i want is..
`$('#kkkk').change(function(){ var r =$(this).val(); });
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){ 
r=$('#kkkk').change(); //should be called once
r++; //now r value change from here
}`
EDIT: ALSO `for` is inside other function

Answer (score 0):

You can bind [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler, it will be triggered only when user selection is a changed option.

```
$('#kkkk').change(function(){

});
```

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: It if fire if value of select is changed if the same option is selected again it wont fire.

Comment: Let say i use it like `$('#kkkk').change(function(){
var r =$(this).val();
});`
and call it using `$('#kkkk').change();` inside for loop and increment `r++`
will it call r value from method or for loop.
like this 
`for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
r=$('#kkkk').change();//should be call one time if dropdown change
r++
}`
I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$('#kkkk').on('change',function(){
    console.log("changed");
    console.log('' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event like this

```
$('#kkkk').on('change',function(){
  // do your stuff
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
$("#kkkk").change(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsezS/)